# how to substitute multiple forward slash with a single slash

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Im having some problems with multiple slashes in filenames, and i want to substitute these to a single slash.

These are generated on the basis of multiple bash script calling one another.

So it are filenames like

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3//dir4////text3.txt
```

Which should be replaces by something that looks like

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/text3.txt
```

It is running within an bash script so it should use basic stuff like sed or similar.

Thanks

Comment: Kindly do always add your efforts in your post which you have put in order to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
sed -E 's#/+#/#g'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/text3.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding `-E` option to `sed` will allow us to add ERE to solution. Unlike usual separator of `sed` which is `/` using `#` as a separator of `sed` command(to avoid confusion, since OP's samples have `/` in Input_file so its better to use a different separator) then mentioning `/+` will substitute all occurrences of `/` which are together with a single `/` `g` flag will make sure its happening globally in line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *"squeeze"* option of `tr`:

```
echo "/dir1/dir2/dir3//dir4////text3.txt" | tr -s '/'
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/text3.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' FS="/+" OFS="/" file
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/text3.txt
```

Setting input Field Separator to one or more `/+`, the set Output FS to one `/`

Comment: Now, don't get me wrong, this answer is useful.   But ya gotta love the awk answers that are absolute gibberish when you're familiar with sed's `s///` replacement syntax.  What's the random `1` following the curly braces?  Why do you even need to assign $1 to $1 if you've got separate input and output field separators?

Comment: @stevesliva `1`is just a test, and since its always true, do the default action, print. `1` =  `{print $0}`